# Extract websites links from a text in R

Tags: r

I have multiple texts that each may consist references to one or more web links. for example:

```
 text1= "s@1212a as www.abcd.com asasa11".
```

How do I extract:

```
   "www.abcd.com"
```

from this text in R? In other words I am looking to extract patterns that start with `www` and end with `.com`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**regmatches** This approach uses `regexpr`/`grepgexpr` and `regmatches`.  I expanded the test data to include more examples.

```
text1 <- c("s@1212a www.abcd.com www.cats.com", 
           "www.boo.com", 
           "asdf",
           "blargwww.test.comasdf")

# Regular expressions take some practice.
# check out ?regex or the wikipedia page on regular expressions
# for more info on creating them yourself.
pattern <- "www\\..*?\\.com"
# Get information about where the pattern matches text1
m <- gregexpr(pattern, text1)
# Extract the matches from text1
regmatches(text1, m)
```

Which gives

```
> regmatches(text1, m) ##
[[1]]
[1] "www.abcd.com" "www.cats.com"

[[2]]
[1] "www.boo.com"

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "www.test.com"
```

Notice it returns a list.  If we want a vector you can just use `unlist` on the result.  This is because we used `gregexpr` which implies there could be multiple matches in our string.  If we know there is at most one match we could use `regexpr` instead

```
> m <- regexpr(pattern, text1)
> regmatches(text1, m)
[1] "www.abcd.com" "www.boo.com"  "www.test.com"
```

Notice, however, that this returns all results as a vector and only returns a single result from each string (note that www.cats.com isn't in the results).  On the whole, though, I think either of these two methods is preferable to the `gsub` method because that way will return the entire input if there is no result found.  For example take a look:

```
> gsub(text1, pattern=".*(www\\..*?\\.com).*", replace="\\1")
[1] "www.abcd.com" "www.boo.com"  "asdf"         "www.test.com"
```

And that's even after modifying the pattern to be a little more robust.  We still get 'asdf' in the results even though it clearly doesn't match the pattern.

Shameless silly self promotion: `regmatches` was introduced with R 2.14 so if you're stuck with an earlier version of R you might be out of luck.  Unless you're able to install the future2.14 package [from my github repo](https://github.com/Dasonk/future2.14) which provides some support for functions introduced in 2.14 to earlier versions of R.

**strapplyc**. An alternative which gives the same result as ## above is:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(test1, pattern)
```

**The regular expression** Here is some explanation on how to decipher the regular expression:

```
pattern <- "www\\..*?\\.com"
```

Explanation:

`www` matches the www portion

`\\.` We need to escape an actual 'dot' character using `\\` because a plain `.` represents "any character" in regular expressions.

`.*?` The `.` represents any character, the `*` tells to match 0 or more times, and the `?` following the `*` tells it to not be greedy. Otherwise "asdf www.cats.com  www.dogs.com asdf" would match all of "www.cats.com www.dogs.com" as a single match instead of recognizing that there are two matches in there.

`\\.` Once again we need to escape an actual dot character

`com` This part matches the ending 'com' that we want to match

Putting it all together it says: start with www. then match any characters until you reach the first ".com"

Comment: Also note that it does extract www.test.com from blargwww.test.comasdf which may or may not be desirable but with no input about this case I decided to allow for it.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That's a nice approach as well - Why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: I have added it to your answer.

Comment: I added some explanation about the regular expression - hopefully this makes it easier for a regex newbie to follow the answer...

Answer (score 7):

Check out the gsub function:

```
x = "s@1212a as www.abcd.com asasa11"
gsub(x=x, pattern=".*(www.*com).*", replace="\\1")
```

The basic idea is to surround the txt you want to retain in parenthesis, then replace the entire line with it.  The replace parameter of gsub "\\1" refers to what was found in the parenthesis.

Comment: I don't think this one is good. For example , this will extract word like *wwwabcdcom* and will extract just.

Comment: gsub(x=x, pattern=".*(www\\..*\\.com).*", "\\1") will make sure the dots are there after www and before com, but it's harder to follow for someone not familar with regular expressions.

Comment: @Kith even this one is not good if you have 2 webs links for example. Come on, if you think the OP is not familiar with regular expressions you should explains better what you have done. For example the meaning of `\\1` needs more explanation.

Comment: Note that if the pattern isn't found in the string this method returns the entire input back - which might not be desirable...

Answer (score 2):

The solutions here are great and in base.  For those that want a quick solution you can use `qdap`'s `genXtract`.  This functions basically takes a left and a right element(s) and it will extract everything in between.  By setting `with = TRUE` it will include those elements:

```
text1 <- c("s@1212a www.abcd.com www.cats.com", 
    "www.boo.com", 
    "asdf",
    "http://www.talkstats.com/ and http://stackoverflow.com/",
    "blargwww.test.comasdf")

library(qdap)
genXtract(text1, "www.", ".com", with=TRUE)

## > genXtract(text1, "www.", ".com", with=TRUE)
## $`www.  :  .com1`
## [1] "www.abcd.com" "www.cats.com"
## 
## $`www.  :  .com2`
## [1] "www.boo.com"
## 
## $`www.  :  .com3`
## character(0)
## 
## $`www.  :  .com4`
## [1] "www.talkstats.com"
## 
## $`www.  :  .com5`
## [1] "www.test.com"
```

PS if you look at code for the function it is a wrapper for Dason's solution.