# What is the mistake in this two lines of code? Getting pattern: "http:// blabla .nc"

Tags: r, regex, gsub, readlines

I have hundreds of TXT files which contain many things and some download links.

The pattern of the download links are like this:

**start with:** http://

and

**end with:** .nc

I created a sample text file for your convenience that you could download from this link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5crmleli2ppa1rm/textfile_including_https.txt?dl=1

Based on this topic in Stackoverflow, I tried to extract all download links from the text file:

[Extract websites links from a text in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579119/extract-websites-links-from-a-text-in-r)

**Here is my code:**

```
download_links <- readLines(file.choose())
All_my_links <- gsub(download_links, pattern=".*(http://.*nc).*", replace="\\1")
```

But it returns all lines, too, **while I only want to extract the http links ended with .nc**

Here is the result:

```
head(All_my_links )
tail(All_my_links )

> head(All_my_links )

[1] "#!/bin/bash"                                                                                                                                                                              
[2] "##############################################################################"                                                                                                           
[3] "version=1.3.2"                                                                                                                                                                            
[4] "CACHE_FILE=.$(basename $0).status"                                                                                                                                                        
[5] "openId="                                                                                                                                                                                  
[6] "search_url='https://esgf-node.llnl.gov/esg-search/wget/?distrib=false&dataset_id=CMIP6.HighResMIP.MIROC.NICAM16-9S.highresSST-present.r1i1p1f1.day.pr.gr.v20190830|esgf-data2.diasjp.net'"

> tail(All_my_links )

[1] "MYPROXY_STATUS=$HOME/.MyProxyLogon"                                 
[2] "COOKIE_JAR=$ESG_HOME/cookies"                                       
[3] "MYPROXY_GETCERT=$ESG_HOME/getcert.jar"                              
[4] "CERT_EXPIRATION_WARNING=$((60 * 60 * 8))   #Eight hour (in seconds)"
[5] ""                                                                   
[6] "WGET_TRUSTED_CERTIFICATES=$ESG_HOME/certificates"
```

**What is my mistake in the code?**

Any comment would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I was tracking such a mystic thing for days. Until i figured out that some hidden character blew it up. Just a thought.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.  You just don't have any matching data.

Comment: Thanks you both for your comments. Actually, I have matching data in the text file. However, it still does NOT work, properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub()` is not for extracting, that's what's wrong with your code. It's for replacing. (See `help("gsub")`). For the purposes of this demonstration, I will use the following data:

```
x <- c("abc", "123", "http://site.nc")
```

(I will not, as a rule, download data posted here as a link. Most others won't also. If you want to share example data, it's best to do so by including in your question the output from `dput()`).

Let's see what happens with your `gsub()` approach:

```
gsub(pattern = ".*(http://.*nc).*", replacement = "\\1", x = x)
# [1] "abc"            "123"            "http://site.nc"
```

Looks familiar. What's going on here is `gsub()` looks at each element of `x`, and replaces each occurrence of `pattern` with `replacement`, which in this case is itself. You will always get the exact same character vector back with that approach.

I would suggest `stringr::str_extract()`:

```
stringr::str_extract(string = x, pattern = ".*http://.*nc.*")
# [1] NA               NA               "http://site.nc"
```

If you wrap this in `na.omit()`, it gives you the output I think you want:

```
na.omit(stringr::str_extract(string = x, pattern = ".*http://.*nc.*"))
# [1] "http://site.nc"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works **if** in each line you only have a link. But lets say your string is like this: `x <- c("abc", "123", "pr_day_MRI-AGCM http://site.nc")` . Then if you run the code: `na.omit(stringr::str_extract(string = x, pattern = ".*http://.*nc.*"))` you will get a mess result like: `[1] "pr_day_MRI-AGCM http://site.nc"` . So, how we can remove the extra characters in each line? For example, `pr_day_MRI-AGCM` in the result.

Comment: I got the answer. BIG THANKS TO YOU. Just be removing the `.*` from the `pattern = ".*http://.*nc.*"` .